# How to post a generic list through a webrequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a website that uploads files in a temp folder each file have its own entered data such as type and description entered by the user i have created a list that have 3 properties

```
Type
Desc
fileBytes
```

each file i upload i create an object for it filled with its data i need to post the list of file Objects i have create to a WebService in another server this webservice will take these data and save it on a Database i just need that part that pass the list to the web service and how to catch it from there